# Find the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial z}{\partial u},\frac{\partial z}{\partial v},\frac{\partial z}{\partial w}$

Tags: partial-derivative, chain-rule

> $z=x^2+xy^3, x=uv^3+w^2, y=u+ve^w$, Find the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial z}{\partial u},\frac{\partial z}{\partial v},\frac{\partial z}{\partial w}$ when $u=1,v=2,w=0$

$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}=2x\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+y^3\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+3xy^2\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}
$$
How do I deal with it since we have I think 6 variables, any hints would be helpful.

Comment: You can find $\partial z / \partial u$ from the last equation you have set up. Similarly $\partial z / \partial v$ etc. For given value of $u, v, w$ you can find $x, y$ and then $z$ from given equations (for example, $x=uv^3+w^2$). Once you know $u, v, w, x, y, z$, that should lead to finding the values of $\partial z / \partial u$ and others.

Comment: @MathLover okay, so $x=8,y=3,z=64+8.27=280$.

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: @MathLover Thats fine, but how do I go forward, thats my doubt is.

Comment: $\partial x / \partial u = v^3$ for example.

Comment: Similarly find others and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}=2x\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+y^3\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+3xy^2\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}$